# Execute specific command according to user existence

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a batch file, I need to check if given user exists, then execute different commands according to results.

Username is taken as a parameter during bat file call on cmd.

What I want is something like that:

```
IF userExists (
    do something
) else (
    do something else
)
```

Following code can retrieve number of matching results, but I failed to use it in IF statement.

```
set username=%1
set searchUser="net user |find /c %username% "
for /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (%searchUser%) do set userCount=%%i
```

I expect to use `userCount` in if statement, but failed to do so.

How can I use my `userCount` in if statement, or is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Your task doesn't make any sense to me. You shouldn't have more than one user with the same name on your local system, so what are you trying to determine? Despite this, even if there were two users with the same name, the output of the `net user` command may look like this, `Administrator            FallenAngel              FallenAngel` and because `Find /C` only counts matching lines, this would return `1` despite there clearly being `2`. Is your task just trying to determine if there is simply a user with that name on the local system? If it is, then please see my answer, which should work.

Comment: @Compo my main goal is to determine whether user exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `%username%` is a predefined environment variable, select somethig else like `myuser`

As per your original attempt using the count.

```
@echo off
set myname=%~1
for /F %%i IN ('net user ^| find /I /C "%myname% "') do (
if not "%%i"=="0" (
   echo found %%i Matches of username
  ) else (
   echo %%i matches found.
 )
)
```

Else, using `%errorlevel%`

```
@echo off
set "myuser=%~1"
net user |findstr /I /R /C:"\<%myuser%\>"
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
   echo %myuser% does NOT exist!
 ) else (
   echo %myuser% exists!
)
```

Alternatively in a `for` loop:

```
@echo off
set "myuser=%~1"
for /f %%i in ('net user ^| findstr /I /R /C:"\<%myuser%\>"') do (
   if /i "%%i"=="%myuser%" echo myusers exists!
  ) else (
   echo %myuser% does NOT exist!
 )
)
```

Comment: first approach do not work for me. Both existing, and non-existing usenames returns _user exists_ message

Comment: @GerhardBarnard You could add a space at the end in the first example (`/C:"^%myuser% "`) so it will match only full username.

Comment: @montonero, yes thanks. but ammended it with word boundaries.

Comment: @FallenAngel you have 3 possible versions now. :) if you however want to not see the results of the commands, you can redirect output to `nul` i.e `net user |findstr /I /R /C:"\<%myuser%\>" >nul 2>&1`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, the word boundary is also valid but it still should be searched from a start of the line since there could be other matching words `/C:"^%myuser%\>"`.

Comment: @montonero: on my systems, `net user` lists them in colums - three in a line - therefore "start of the line" isn't an option.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard first approach suits me fine and works like a charm. thanks (:

Sipliy, I avoid errorlevel usage, so I do not tested the second approach, but thanks for the option (:

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to determine if a particular user account exists, instead of how many matching user names exist on the same PC, then I'd suggest this [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) alternative:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ProfilePath="
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC UserAccount Where^
 "LocalAccount='TRUE' And Name='%~1'" Get SID 2^>Nul') Do For /F %%B In ("%%A"
) Do For /F "Tokens=2Delims==" %%C In ('WMIC Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "SID='%%B' And Special!='True'" Get LocalPath /Value 2^>Nul'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%D In ("%%C") Do Set "ProfilePath=%%D"
If Defined ProfilePath (Echo User Profile %1 exists at %ProfilePath%) Else (
    Echo User Profile %1 does not exist)
Pause
```

The `If` command along with the `Pause` are included just to show you an `If`|`Else` structure for your further commands, *(they could obviously be modified/changed as required)*.

If you do not need to know and/or access the user profile path, you can simplify the command considerably:

```bat
@Echo Off
WMIC UserAccount Where "LocalAccount='TRUE' And Name='%~1'" Get SID 2>Nul|Find "S-">Nul && (
    Echo User Profile %1 exists) || Echo User Profile %1 does not exist
Pause
```

Comment: Execution time for this script is quite long . It takes nearly a minute to echo the result when I run the `bat`` file through `cmd`? Is that normal?

Comment: @FallenAngel, how many times did you try it? If [tag:wmic] has never been used on the system, it runs through some configuration processes, once that has happened it should work considerably quicker! Please, try it again and let me know if it has made any difference to the execution speed.

Comment: I tried for a few times. Like 10 or more. Execution time is quite long

Comment: @FallenAngel, try the simplified version I've added to the foot of my answer, which does not try to get the profile path, and see if it improves your execution speed.

Comment: simplified script also had similar issues. A small search show me that WMI have performance issues when used on a computer on a large network. Even your query have `LocalAccount` filter on, this still make me suspicious about the consistency of the WMI.

Comment: @FallenAngel, other than the issue with first run, the command should return the result easily with very little noticeable delay unless you have a problem with the PC, _or you've changed something_. There can be problems with it on large networks but, as our command is specifically filtering on `LocalAccount` it shouldn't be a major bottleneck. What happens when you reverse the filters, `Where "Name='%~1' And LocalAccount='TRUE''" Get`